# set_until method doesn't works for TwitterUserOrder()

Tags: python, twitter, screen-scraping

I am scraping news feed from a twitter user timeline. I would like to get only the feeds posted in the last 24hours. I am using TwitterSearch library and specifically using TwitterUserOrder to have access to a user timeline. However, I cannot use 'set_until' and get ALL the tweets of the timeline.

'set_until' works for TwitterSearchOrder, and not 'TwitterUserOrder' which is weird.

I get this error :

> AttributeError: 'TwitterUserOrder' object has no attribute 'set_until'

Anyone has the same issue ?

```
import datetime as DT
from TwitterSearch import TwitterUserOrder

today = DT.date.today()
days_ago = today - DT.timedelta(days=1)


tuo = TwitterUserOrder('SnowflakeDB')
tuo.set_include_entities(False) 
tuo.set_until(days_ago)
tuo.arguments.update({'tweet_mode':'extended'})
tuo.arguments.update({'truncated': 'False' })`
```